# Decimals missing in Division Output

Tags: sql, casting, decimal, division

I'm a rookie SQL Programmer, but have searched here and many other SQL Forums and can't figure out why my simple division script is still ignoring the decimals.  I've CAST EVERYTHING as Decimal, but still don't get any in the output . .

```
(CAST((ABS(CAST(CAST(SUM(h4qqnb) AS DECIMAL(12,4)) - CAST(SUM(h4hdnb) AS DECIMAL(12,4))AS DECIMAL(12,4)))/CAST(SUM(h4hdnb) AS DECIMAL(12,4))) AS DECIMAL(10,2))*100)||'%' AS Count_Variance_Rate,
```

What am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMs you are using

Answer (score 0):

That's a seriously ugly expression, with far too much CASTing, but essentially what you're doing (just looking at the outermost CAST statement) is saying

```
CAST(someNumber as DECIMAL(10,2)
```

which is going to give you a number with two decimal places of precision.  You're then multiplying that by 100, which is going to give you an integer.

If you're trying to get a percentage value formatted to two decimal places, you can do it like this, assuming that h4qqnb and h4hdnb are decimal fields to begin with:

```
concat(cast(cast(abs(sum(h4qqnb) - sum(h4hdnb)) / sum(h4hdnb) as decimal(10, 4)) * 100 as decimal(10, 2)), '%') as Count_Variance_Rate2
```

Working example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/279752/5/0